# how to load image from django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i want to load the picture from `model`. but i get "`<QuerySet [<Photo: ira>]>`" except of photo.

i have tried to use `photo.url`, `photo.image.url`, `photo.image`, `photo.image.image` but it does not work

`my templtate`:

```
<div id="userInfo">
            <img src="{{ photo.url }}" alt="{{ username }}">
            <div id="statusAndName">
                <h1>{{ username }}</h1>
                <h3>{{ status }}</h3>
            </div>
</div>
```

`my view`:

```py
def UserPage(request,user_num):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_num)
    #get user info
    username = user.username
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user.id)
    photo = Photo.objects.filter(user=user.id)
    status = user.status
    return render(
        request,
        'userpage.html',
        context={'username': username, 'posts': posts, 'status': status, 'photo': photo},
    )
```

`my models`:

```py
class Photo(models.Model):
    """
    A typical class defining a model, derived from the Model class.
    """

    # Fields
    user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="user's id")
    photo = models.ImageField()
    

    # Metadata
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-user"]

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String for representing the MyModelName object (in Admin site etc.)
        """
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.filter` which returns a queryset. Since you have a one to one relationship between user and photo, there can be only one photo for a user, so simply change to

```
photo = Photo.objects.get(user=user.id)
```

which should return the `photo` object if it exists. As Pietro mentioned, you'll need to use `photo.photo.url` in your template.

Side note, depending on how you want to handle errors when the photo does not exist, you can either handle `DoesNotExist` errors or keep using `.filter` and get the first item if it exists

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is because the object `Photo` has a sub-field "photo".
Try this:

```
<div id="userInfo">
            <img src="{{ photo.photo.url }}" alt="{{ username }}">
            <div id="statusAndName">
                <h1>{{ username }}</h1>
                <h3>{{ status }}</h3>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the src is empty (

Comment: Control that the field of photo is not empty. Onother thing, in view function "UserPage" try this: Photo.objects.filter(user=user)